# Trying to up a server on MERN returning error

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mern

I'm new on MERN, last year our MERN programmer as get out of company, so he trained me for 2 weeks on MERN, then project stoped for 12 months, in this time my computer has been erased, and now I need to get back on project, I donwload it from gitlab, instaled node, npm, run npm install on server dir, and when I run npm start terminal show this:

```
> server@1.0.0 start /Users/usuarios/eventos/server
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
buffer.js:331
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function hidden
    at Function.from (buffer.js:331:9)
    at fnv1a32 (/Users/usuarios/eventos/server/node_modules/mongoose-uuid2/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/fnv1a.js:21:25)
at fnv1a24 (/Users/usuarios/eventos/server/node_modules/mongoose-uuid2/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/fnv1a.js:39:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usuarios/eventos/server/node_modules/mongoose-uuid2/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:14:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/usuarios/eventos/server/node_modules/mongoose-uuid2/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:7:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I already tried update npm,  update node, reinstall all packages nothing work.
node: v14.4.0
npm: 6.14.5

my package Json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "async-redis": "^1.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.8",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "form-data": "^2.5.1",
    "http-errors": "^1.7.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "localenv": "^0.2.2",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.19",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "mongoose-uuid2": "^2.3.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "npm": "^6.14.5",
    "superagent": "^5.2.2",
    "to-uuid": "^0.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

Is there something that I missed? Is there something that I can do?
Thanks for your help;

Comment: the issue seems to be in `mongoose-uuid2` which has not been updated in more than a year. [link](https://github.com/niahmiah/mongoose-uuid/issues/22) - remove the dependency and use another uuid package or try downgrade your version of node

Comment: Thank u so much @SamuelG, this project has been archived, so for now I just downgrade my node and some dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Samuel for your comment, this helped me to find that mongoose-uiid2 has been archived and will probably not receive new versions, so for now I downgraded my node, and bcrypt untill we change this module. Thanks for your help

Comment: Np. You can run a node version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage multiple versions of node in your dev environment.

Comment: I downgraded to node v10 for my mongoose-uuid2 to work again